# Multiple actions in a form?

Tags: plugins

I have two plugins that I want to use in a single form.  One is a Guest Entry plugin to save the data submitted in the form, and the other is a Plugin that sends an email notification when the form is submitted.

I want to use both of these in the same form but I'm not sure how.  If I have

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="guestEntries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="formNotification/getForm">
```

It won't work since both have the name "action"
and I can't change the name or the functions never get called.

What can I do to make both of them work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s not possible for a form to simultaneously invoke two controller actions.

You would need to write a plugin that provides its own [controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers), which in turn could be used to invoke the other controller actions.

```
class MyPluginController
{
    public function actionSaveEntryAndSendNotification()
    {
        // Save the entry
        craft()->runController('guestEntries/saveEntry');

        // Send the notification
        craft()->runController('formNotification/getForm');
    }
}
```

If "FormNotificationController" is already your own custom plugin, then it might make more sense to just call `craft()->runController('guestEntries/saveEntry');` from the top of `actionGetForm()`. Or just save the entry yourself from the controller action – the Guest Entries plugin is really pretty simple; most of the heavy lifting is provided by the [EntriesService - saveEntry() API](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/entriesservice#saveEntry).

Answer (score 3):

You can't run multiple actions in one request. What you're looking to do is trigger your notification action after the [`entries.saveEntry`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#entries-onSaveEntry) event. I'm assuming that your `formNotification` plugin is a custom plugin that you wrote. Fortunately, [events are easy](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-and-events#listening-for-events):

```
craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    // Your notification code here.
});
```

The best place to add this event listener is in your plugin's `init` function. This is located in the main plugin file.

Answer (score 0):

How would you write this in Craft CMS 3 / Yii2?

```
class MyPluginController
{
    public function actionSaveEntryAndSendNotification()
    {
        // Save the entry
        craft()->runController('guestEntries/saveEntry');

        // Send the notification
        craft()->runController('formNotification/getForm');
    }
}
```

Comment: Think I've found a solution

  Craft::$app->runAction('guestEntries/saveEntry');
  Craft::$app->runAction('formNotification/getForm);

Comment: Want to edit your original post and add your comment as an official answer?